# Problem with modeless Form Window, which implements IWin32Window

Tags: c#, winforms, revit-api

I tried to follow the logic, described on Jeremy's post here:

https://jeremytammik.github.io/tbc/a/0088_revit_window_handle.htm

First - what is a goal.

The goal is to create a Win Form window, which would start with Revit Application and close with Revit Application. Window is in modeless dialog and displays the output of different actions/commands which are happening while working in Revit Document. Everything works fine for me, except for the part, that with each Revit Command new instance of Form Window is created. I would like to **keep only one window which hides and shows**, whenever any action is taken.

Below where I came so far - I hope anyone could be able to direct me which path to go....

Win Form Class:

```
public partial class CmdWindowHandleForm : Form
{
        public string LabelText
        {
            get{ return _labelText.Text; }
            set{ _labelText.Text = value; }
        }

        public CmdWindowHandleForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}

partial class CmdWindowHandleForm
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

            this._labelText = new Label();
            this._labelText.Text = string.Empty;

            this.Controls.Add(this._labelText);
        }
}
```

Class with WindowHandle, which is used as argument when Form.Show() method is called:

```
public class WindowHandle : IWin32Window
{
        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get{ return _handleWindow; }
        }

        IntPtr _handleWindow;

        public WindowHandle(IntPtr handleWindow)
        {
            _handleWindow = handleWindow;
        }
}
```

And lastly my static class of InfoConsole window, which would run along Revit app:

```
public static class InfoConsole
{
        public static CmdWindowHandleForm Window
        {
            get{ return _window; }
        }

        static WindowHandle _hWndRevit = null;
        static CmdWindowHandleForm _window = null;

        public static void Show(string message)
        {
            if (_hWndRevit == null)
            {
                Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

                IntPtr h = process.MainWindowHandle;
                _hWndRevit = new WindowHandle(h);
            } 
            if(InfoConsole._window == null)
            {
                _window = new CmdWindowHandleForm();
                _window.Show(_hWndRevit as IWin32Window);
            }
            else
            {
                _window.Visible = true;
            }
            _window.AddText(message);
        }
}
```

And while running a command (implementing IExternalCommand - interface required to access Revit DB) method is simply called:
`InfoConsole.Show(outputMessage);`

Any help much appreciated...
Lukasz

Comment: Just check if _window is null in the Show() command.  If it is not null then you know you don't want to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

The code you refer to is way out of date. It was published by The Building Coder in February **2009**: [Revit Window Handle and Modeless Dialogues](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/revit-window-handle-and-modeless-dialogues.html).

Access to the Revit main window handle changed in **2018**: [Revit Window Handle and Parenting an Add-In Form](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/11/revit-window-handle-and-parenting-an-add-in-form.html).

Answer (score -1):

This question was also raised and discussed in the Revit API discussion forum: [Problem with modeless Form Window, which implements IWin32Window](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/problem-with-modeless-form-window-which-implements-iwin32window/td-p/11736921). Please refer to that for further, continued discussion and the final solution, still under development as I write this.